# How do I debug (suspected) HDCP issues?

Tags: macos, safari, web-browser, streaming, hdcp

I have a 2021 14" MacBook Pro running macOS 12.4 (21F79) that won't display streaming video in Safari when connected (Thunderbolt) to a LG UltraFine 5K display.

It does the classic thing of playing audio but blacking out the video. If I use another browser, basically anything non-WebKit, it works perfectly well.

Thunderbolt is the only connection to this particular LG display and using HDMI with my TV doesn't trigger the issue.

Any hints as to how I can debug this issue so I can file a bug report or something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would start with the system profile report and send a sysdiagnose to Apple as a starter.

- https://developer.apple.com/bug-reporting/profiles-and-logs/?platform=macos

You need to be a developer or part of a customer seed for some profiles, but this is a standard logging request in my eyes.

While Apple is chewing on the report I might try searching the consolidated logs, but that can be a needle in the haystack without engineering helping to guide me with a search predicate to find the relevant entries.

- https://eclecticlight.co/2022/08/27/explainer-subsystems/
- https://eclecticlight.co/2022/08/26/unified-log-structure-and-available-data/